# apex:actionFunction action doesn't seem to work the same as apex:commandButton action

Tags: visualforce, standardcontroller, actionfunction, commandbutton

I am trying to override a custom object new and edit actions with a simple visualforce page.  The desire is to not need a custom controller and just use the standard controller methods.

```
<apex:page standardController="Site__c" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />
        ...
    </apex:form >
</apex:page>
```

Which works fine, but when I try to move the save action to apex:actionFunction, and use the oncomplete to redirect.

```
<apex:page standardController="Site__c" >
    <script>
        function redirectBack(){...;}
    </script>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:actionFunction name="saveActionFunc" action="{!save}" oncomplete="redirectBack()" rerender="theBlock" />
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" onClick="saveActionFunc();"/>
        ...
    </apex:form >
</apex:page>
```

the redirectBack() is working, but it doesn't save the form.

***Can you use apex:actionFunction to call standardController methods?***

Note: I realized that apex:commandButton has oncomplete too, so I am not looking so much for a better way, but to better understand the limitations of actionFunction.

The [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) on each reads very similar, except one is called by AJAX request and the other by a DOM event.  Also the the commandButton adds:

```
Note that command buttons associated with the save, edit, or delete actions in a 
standard controller are rendered only if the user has the appropriate permissions. 
Likewise, command buttons associated with the edit and delete actions are rendered 
only if a record is associated with the page.
```

but I don't believe that means that only commandButtons can call standard controller methods, but what do I know.

Can anyone say for sure?

Comment: I have action and oncomplete- action will update the object.but when i run, action is not calling only oncomplete works